# iPhone Push Notification Problem with Ad Hoc Provision

Tags: iphone, release, push-notification, provisioning, adhoc

The iPhone i'm developing with (building the application to, not installed via ad-hoc) receives push notifications as it should.  I've got an application that just sends dummy push notifications on command, and the dev iphone receives them consistently.  However, I've distributed a beta build under the release configuration to several co-workers, and none of these builds of the app have received a single push notification.  I've confirmed that the app prompts the user on first run for permission to receive push notifications, and I've also confirmed that everyone has answered "yes" to this prompt.  Has anyone else experienced this problem?  I feel like it has something to do with provisioning, but the apple developer portal is so vague about things, I very well could be missing something important.

Comment: To add to my description - other than not receiving any push notifications, the app runs normally.  The provider server picks up the device token that the ad-hoc version of the apps send out just fine.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Looks like I missed the part in apples push documentation where it states that apps distributed via ad-hoc use the apple production push gateway, not the apple dev push gateway.  I was under the assumption that while developing the application, I always wanted to use the "development" push gateway...but that's what I get for using common sense.

Comment: I just lost about 3 hours because of this. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'd just fallen into this trap, but I'm glad it's this way round so at least you can confirm your production setup is all working before you release.

Comment: I spent about 6 hours on this after thinking at first that it was iOS5 being on my device and figuring out how to downgrade. Great share.

Comment: In addition to changing `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` to `gateway.push.apple.com`, make sure you're using the production cert and key.

Comment: Wasting 4 hours hit my head against the wall until I find this. Thanks man.

Comment: Any updates in 2014 ? Lost *days*, without pushing anything to the ad hoc version, using production certs